# I am designing signup page, every time it displays your password dont match

Tags: php

I am trying to design a signup page using the code below. Every time I submit the form, it returns with `else` condition, please guide me where I am wrong.

```
<?php
    session_start();

    $localhost= 'localhost';
    $username= 'SK';
    $password="29336";
    $db = "Internship";
    $con= mysqli_connect($localhost,$username,$password,$db);
    if (isset($_POST['reg_user']))
    {
        $name= $_POST['name'];
        $email= $_POST['email'];
        $psd= md5($_POST['psw']);
        $confirm_psd= $_POST['confirm_psw'];
        if ($psd == $confirm_psd)
        {
            $query = "INSERT INTO register (name, email, password) 
                      VALUES('.$name.', '$email', '$psd')";
            mysqli_query($con, $query);
            echo 'inserted';
        }
        else
        {
            echo "your password dont match ";
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: Maybe `$psd` doesn't match `$confirm_psd`

Comment: in both cases it is displaying "your password dont match"

Comment: On a sidenote: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords and https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection

Comment: don't use `md5` for hashing your passwords ( md5 is broken ) and do use a prepared statement ( avoid sql injection to which this code is vulnerable ). Also `'.$name.'` is incorrect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Important note

If you're using this code for anything requiring real security (i.e. not just a student project) MD5 is not an appropriate hashing algorithm. Read through the [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Main_Page) advice to learn how to do this properly.

## Answering your question

You have:

```
$psd= md5($_POST['psw']);
$confirm_psd= $_POST['confirm_psw'];
if ($psd == $confirm_psd)
{
    ...
```

which looks like you're comparing the plain text value of `confirm_psd` with the MD5 hashed value of `psw`, which obviously won't match.

I'd suggest you either do the comparison before hashing the `psw` field, like:

```
$confirm_psd= $_POST['confirm_psw'];
if ($_POST['psw'] == $confirm_psd)
{
    $psd= md5($_POST['psw']);
    ...
```

Or also hash the `confirm_psw` value before the comparison like this:

```
$psd= md5($_POST['psw']);
$confirm_psd= md5($_POST['confirm_psw']);
if ($psd == $confirm_psd)
{
    ...
```

and then your comparison should work as you expect.